# How to SUM from MySQL for every n record

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a following result from query:

```
+---------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
| order_main_id | S36  | S37  | S38  | S39  | S40  | S41  | S42  | total |
+---------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
|            26 |  127 |  247 |  335 |  333 |  223 |  111 |   18 |  1394 | 
|            26 |  323 |  606 |  772 |  765 |  573 |  312 |  154 |  3505 | 
|            38 |   25 |   35 |   35 |   35 |   20 | NULL | NULL |   150 | 
|            38 |   25 |   35 |   35 |   35 |   20 | NULL | NULL |   150 | 
|            39 |   65 |   86 |   86 |   42 |   21 | NULL | NULL |   300 | 
|            39 |   42 |   58 |   58 |   28 |   14 | NULL | NULL |   200 | 
|            35 |   11 |   20 |   21 |   18 |    9 |    2 | NULL |    81 | 
|            35 |   10 |   25 |   30 |   23 |   12 |    1 | NULL |   101 | 
+---------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
```

I would like to insert a SUM before enter different `order_main_id`, it would be like this result:

```
+---------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
| order_main_id | S36  | S37  | S38  | S39  | S40  | S41  | S42  | total |
+---------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
|            26 |  127 |  247 |  335 |  333 |  223 |  111 |   18 |  1394 | 
|            26 |  323 |  606 |  772 |  765 |  573 |  312 |  154 |  3505 |
|               |  450 |  853 | 1107 | 1098 |  796 |  423 |  172 |  4899 | 
|            38 |   25 |   35 |   35 |   35 |   20 | NULL | NULL |   150 | 
|            38 |   25 |   35 |   35 |   35 |   20 | NULL | NULL |   150 |
|               |   50 |   70 |   70 |   70 |   40 | NULL | NULL |   300 | 
|            39 |   65 |   86 |   86 |   42 |   21 | NULL | NULL |   300 | 
|            39 |   42 |   58 |   58 |   28 |   14 | NULL | NULL |   200 |
|               |  107 |  144 |  144 |   70 |   35 | NULL | NULL |   500 | 
|            35 |   11 |   20 |   21 |   18 |    9 |    2 | NULL |    81 | 
|            35 |   10 |   25 |   30 |   23 |   12 |    1 | NULL |   101 |
|               |   21 |   45 |   51 |   41 |   21 |    3 | NULL |   182 | 
+---------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
```

How to make this possible ?

Comment: The second result is not coming from one query, but i insert it manually by hand

Comment: @OP: For reals? Dude, I'm so sorry!

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to write a second Query which makes use of GROUP BY order_main_id.

Something like:

```
SELECT sum(S41+...) FROM yourTable GROUP BY orderMainId
```

K

Comment: Yes, i did a second query like your suggest, that's why a got those value. But i would like to do this by one query. Any thought ?

Comment: No, in my understanding this is not possible with one query. You could achive this by writing a stored procedure which fills a temporary table with the results of your two queries in order to get your desired output.

Comment: Thanks KB22,
This is a light for me, that this is not possible.

Comment: This is definitely possible and not something you need to loop through or do a temp table for. In fact, that's very, very bad advice to solve this problem. Just use a `union all`, and life will be peachy!

Comment: KB22, you are still the best.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually do this in one query, but with a `union all` (really two queries, but the result sets are combined to make one awesome result set):

```
select
    order_main_id,
    S36,
    S37,
    S38,
    S39,
    S40,
    S41,
    S42,
    S36 + S37 + S38 + S39 + S40 + S41 + S42 as total,
    'Detail' as rowtype
from
    tblA
union all
select
    order_main_id,
    sum(S36),
    sum(S37),
    sum(S38),
    sum(S39),
    sum(S40),
    sum(S41),
    sum(S42),
    sum(S36 + S37 + S38 + S39 + S40 + S41 + S42),
    'Summary' as rowtype
from
    tblA
group by
    order_main_id
order by
    order_main_id, RowType
```

Remember that the `order by` affects the entirety of the `union all`, not just the last query. So, your resultset would look like this:

```
+---------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+---------+
| order_main_id | S36  | S37  | S38  | S39  | S40  | S41  | S42  | total | rowtype |
+---------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+---------+
|            26 |  127 |  247 |  335 |  333 |  223 |  111 |   18 |  1394 | Detail  |
|            26 |  323 |  606 |  772 |  765 |  573 |  312 |  154 |  3505 | Detail  |
|            26 |  450 |  853 | 1107 | 1098 |  796 |  423 |  172 |  4899 | Summary |
|            35 |   11 |   20 |   21 |   18 |    9 |    2 | NULL |    81 | Detail  |
|            35 |   10 |   25 |   30 |   23 |   12 |    1 | NULL |   101 | Detail  |
|            35 |   21 |   45 |   51 |   41 |   21 |    3 | NULL |   182 | Summary |
|            38 |   25 |   35 |   35 |   35 |   20 | NULL | NULL |   150 | Detail  |
|            38 |   25 |   35 |   35 |   35 |   20 | NULL | NULL |   150 | Detail  |
|            38 |   50 |   70 |   70 |   70 |   40 | NULL | NULL |   300 | Summary |
|            39 |   65 |   86 |   86 |   42 |   21 | NULL | NULL |   300 | Detail  |
|            39 |   42 |   58 |   58 |   28 |   14 | NULL | NULL |   200 | Detail  |
|            39 |  107 |  144 |  144 |   70 |   35 | NULL | NULL |   500 | Summary |
+---------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+---------+
```

This way, you know what is and what isn't a detail or summary row, and the `order_main_id` that it's for. You could always (and probably should) hide this column in your presentation layer.

Comment: That really works. As S36 until S42 are aliases of another SUM before UNION ALL, those aliases not recoqnized after UNION ALL, so i need to make aliasing again, The rowType is genius addition. Many thanks Eric.

Answer (score 0):

For things like these I think you should use a reporting library(such as Crystal Reports), it'll save you a lot of trouble, check [JasperReports and similar projects on osalt](http://www.osalt.com/jasperreports)