# MYSQL Sum of every 24 rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Please help me to find Sum of every 24 rows (if available) using MYSQL  query
here my table:

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6qtb.png)

Assume we have only three Columns Record#, Sold and SoldAvg, so what will be the query? Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Please be more specific. Add example data, expected output and the query you are stuck with directly to your question

Comment: try this link ..this might solve your problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346117/how-to-sum-from-mysql-for-every-n-record

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try something like this (untested):

```
SET @i := 0;
SELECT SUM(`Sold`), SUM(`SoldAvg`)
FROM (
    SELECT
      @i:=@i+1 as `counter`,
      FLOOR(@i/24) AS `group`,
      `Record#`,
      `Sold`,
      `SoldAvg`
      FROM your_table
      ORDER BY `Record#`
) GROUP BY `group`;
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer did helped me but I solved my problem programmatically.