# Sum of every three rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sum, rows

I have this MySQL table:

```
| id | datetime           | readings | phase    
| 1  | 2017-09-01 20:38:45| 5        | 1 
| 2  | 2017-09-01 20:38:45| 5        | 2
| 3  | 2017-09-01 20:38:45| 5        | 3
| 4  | 2017-09-01 20:39:28| 4        | 1 
| 5  | 2017-09-01 20:39:28| 3        | 2
| 6  | 2017-09-01 20:39:28| 4        | 3
```

Those datas comes from energy monitoring, so every reading have a three rows, for first, second, and third phase. Sum or this three readings should by my energy usage in time.

**I would like to get the sum of every three rows where each will be for the same date and sum of three phases.**

So in this case I would like to receive from MySQL date and sums" (5+5+5), (4+3+4)..

Something like:

```
| datetime           | readings_sum    
| 2017-09-01 20:38:45|    15       
| 2017-09-01 20:39:28|    11
```

Comment: If each group has the same `datetime` then you can simply use: `SELECT datetime, SUM(readings) FROM mytable GROUP BY datetime`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to SUM from MySQL for every n record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346117/how-to-sum-from-mysql-for-every-n-record)

Comment: If the datetimes are different do you care which you get in the result set?

Comment: datatimes are always the same for three phases, I need the reading to make a chart with energy usage. So I need date time on X basis and energy on Y. Of course chart is not part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Since every reading has 3 rows/phases and assuming every phase starts with 1 then you could assign a block number using a variable and then group by to sum the readings. If you want the first or last datetime in a block use min or max.

```
CREATE TABLE T (id INT, DT datetime, readings INT, phase INT);
INSERT INTO T VALUES    
( 1 ,  '2017-09-01 20:38:45' ,5        , 1), 
( 2 ,  '2017-09-01 20:38:45' ,5        , 2),
( 3 ,  '2017-09-01 20:38:47' ,5        , 3),
( 4 ,  '2017-09-01 20:39:28' ,4        , 1),
( 5 ,  '2017-09-01 20:39:28' ,3        , 2),
( 6 ,  '2017-09-01 20:39:28' ,4        , 3);

    SELECT s.phaseblock,max(S.DT),SUM(S.READINGS) SumReadings
FROM
(
SELECT T.*,
         IF(T.PHASE = 1 , @BN:=@BN+1,@BN:=@BN) AS PHASEBLOCK,
         @P:=T.PHASE AS P
FROM T ,(SELECT @BN:=0,@P:=0) BLOCK
ORDER BY T.ID
) S
GROUP BY S.PHASEBLOCK;
```

Result

```
+------------+---------------------+-------------+
| phaseblock | max(S.DT)           | SumReadings |
+------------+---------------------+-------------+
| 1          | 2017-09-01 20:38:47 |          15 |
| 2          | 2017-09-01 20:39:28 |          11 |
+------------+---------------------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.08 sec)
```

Comment: Thank, I will check it